# What kind of relation ship should I make

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am making a flask app where I have 2 tables in a data base.

1. User
2. File

A file has a column called fileOwnerId but I want to add another called allowed viewers.
How would I implement such a situation.

I've had 2 ideas:

1. Is to make a column called validViewers that would store an array of valid viewer but I don't think you can store an array in a db.
2. Is to make a foreign key in User that would connect to only certain File rows. The problem is I don't think you can choose which files would apply to which user.

If theres any other ideas you guys have I'm all ears. Ty in advance

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    userUuid = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    password = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    isAdmin = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default = False)
    files = db.relationship("File")
    
class File(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fileUuid = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    filePath = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    fileName = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    fileOwnerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
```

Comment: a potential solution for this is to implement roles for your users, so you can grant permissions to a role which will be associated with group of users.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 relationships to consider:

Users can own multiple files, 1 to Many relationship

Users can view Multiple Files and a file can be viewed by Multiple Users.  ie Many to Many relationship

The first is handled by adding the owner ID to Files.  The second is solved by creating as intermediate or jump table.

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    userUuid = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    password = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    isAdmin = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default = False)
    files = db.relationship("File")

class FileAccess(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    fileid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)    


class File(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    fileUuid = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    filePath = db.Column(db.String(1000), unique = True)
    fileName = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    fileOwnerId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
```

So if users 1, 4, 6 need access to file 5 the intermediate table looks like this:

```
id    userid   fileid    
 1      1       5
 2      4       5
 3      6       5
```

You can now query FileAccess.fileid to get a list of users who can view the file, or query FileAccess.userid and get a list of files that a user can view.  If you are using an ORM in flask there may be helper functions to make this easier.

Comment: The problem with this is that each file can only have 1 viewer I need to allow multiple people to view each file.

Comment: I've added to the answer.  You might want to look at use sqlalchemy with flask to get their many2many relationship helper functions

Answer (score 0):

Define a model `Role`

```py
class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)

    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if self.permissions is None:
            self.permissions = 0

    def add_permission(self, perm):
        if not self.has_permission(perm):
            self.permissions += perm

    def remove_permission(self, perm):
        if self.has_permission(perm):
            self.permissions -= perm

    def reset_permissions(self):
        self.permissions = 0

    def has_permission(self, perm):
        return self.permissions & perm == perm
```

Define an enum for your permissions:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Permission(Enum):
    READ = 1
    WRITE = 2
    SPECIFIC_PERMISSION = 4
    ANOTHER_SPECIFIC_ERMISSION = 8
    ADMIN = 16
    ...
```

Add `role_id` to your `User` model, and also ways to determine permissions. In this case I have added `is_administrator` but you can implement your own methods to check permissions.

```
class User(...):
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))

    def can(self, perm):
        return self.role is not None and self.role.has_permission(perm)

    def is_administrator(self):
        return self.can(Permission.ADMIN)
```

You can create different roles that have different permissions to handle access to not only files but other stuff.

Comment: Once again this would be a good solution, however I need each file allow certain users and ONLY those users. Just because you have perm 1 doesn't mean you can view files. The problem is I need to store a list of users that can view a file so is there any way to make a list in sqlalchemy db?